# Add response to a Set<String>

Tags: java, for-loop, collections, set

```java
Set<String> response = null;
Set<String> success = null;
for (String country : countrys) {

    response = service.method(country);

    if (response != null) {

        success = response;
    }
}
```

Here `service.method` returns a `Set<String>`. I want to add the response of each loop to the success Set.

Now, this code is just storing the response of the last loop in success.
Can someone please help with this at the earliest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)` method ([see spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)):

```
    Set<String> response = null;
    Set<String> success = new HashSet<>();
    for (String country : countrys) {

        response = service.method(country);

        if (response != null) {
            success.addAll(response);
        }
    }
```

Keep in mind that you will want to initialize `success` as an empty set (e.g. a `HashSet`) first. Otherwise you will run into a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: thank you so much its working. But what if I need a new line after each response? How can I achieve that?

Comment: Finally I will be printing the success. Should I iterate over success and add a /n to each iteration?